# Appengine process file upload direct from stream (JAVA)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload

I'm trying to convert a Java web app to use GAE.

The entire app consists of selecting one or more local (xml) files in a form and hitting submit. On the receiving end, the elements in the xml are sorted and are outputted separately to a `textarea` (one for each input file).

I don't care about the contents of the file once I parse the XML.

Apache Commons File Upload uses a temp location to upload the file, but this is unavailable in GAE.

How do I get an `InputStream` directly for each one of the uploaded files?

**Update**

Here's the final code sample just so you won't have to follow the link in the accepted answer

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload ();
try {
    FileItemIterator uploads = upload.getItemIterator (request);

    while (uploads.hasNext ()) {
        FileItemStream item = uploads.next ();

        if (item.isFormField ()) {
            continue;
        }

        final String filename = item.getName ();

        w.println ("<textarea class='xmlout' readonly='true' cols='150' rows='100' >");

        try {
            doSomethingWith(item.openStream ());
            stream.close ();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // uh oh!
        }

        w.println ("</textarea>");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [this file upload example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java#fileforms) with [`commons-fileupload:1.2.2`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccommons-fileupload%7Ccommons-fileupload%7C1.2.2%7Cjar) and it works as expected (haven't upgraded to 1.3 yet). Example shows how to get to input stream of each uploaded file.